# Loop through classes, get class text value, add together and output to div

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have

```
var val = document.getElementByClassName('duration').text();
var temp = val.split(":");
var total = 0;
var v;
for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    v = parseFloat(temp[i]);
    if (!isNaN(v)) total += v;
    totalmins = parseInt(total / 60);
    totalsecs = parseInt(total % 60);
    total = totalmins + ":" + totalsecs;
}
document.getElementById("total-time").innerHTML = total;
```

for the html

```
<ol id="songs">
    <li class="title"><a href="#" data-src="music/barryNice3.mp3">You don't really love me <span class="duration">3:50</span></a></li>
    <li class="title"><a href="#" data-src="music/newjam.mp3">So done with you <span class="duration">4:23</span></a></li>
    <li class="title"><a href="#" data-src="">I actually still love you<span class="duration">3:57</span></a></li>
    <li class="title"><a href="#" data-src="">Call me back please <span class="duration">4:08</span></a></li>
    <li class="title"><a href="#" data-src="">Bye baby bye <span class="duration">3:15</span></a></li>
    <li class="title"><a href="#" data-src="">We together <span class="duration">3:46</span></a></li>
    <li class="title"><a href="#" data-src="">Together Forever <span class="duration">4:05</span></a></li>
</ol>
```

What I need to do is get the value of duration and add them together and then output that number to a div. I'm totally a noob and I'm stuck.

Comment: You're looking for *document.getElement**s**ByClassName*, which returns a NodeList that doesn't have a *text* method.

Comment: To follow on that...you want to iterate through the items in the collection. It looks like you have some knowledge of iterating through a collection. Also, instead of putting the duration in a span, can you use a data-duration attribute? Might save you some extra steps...

Comment: Of course the typo in getElementsByClassName, is probably what got me so frustrated at this. I didn't notice it so I ended up approaching it in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
> var val = document.getElementByClassName('duration').text();
```

The method you seek is [*getElementsByClassName*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#getelementsbyclassname) (note plural *Elements*), which returns a live [*NodeList*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177), which doesn't have a *text* method.

In this case, it's probably better to use *querySelectorAll*, since that is supported in IE 8 but *getElementsByClassName* isn't, so:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.duration');
```

Now loop over *elements* and get the text:

```
var text;
for (var i=0, ilen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  text = elements[i].textContent || elements[i].innerText;

  // do stuff with text

}
```

Note that the W3C [*textContent*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent) property is supported in older IE as *innerText*.

To sum the time (I guess it's mm:ss) you can do:

```
var b, text, totalTime;
var total = 0;
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.duration');

// Pad single digit with leading zero
function z(n){return (n<10? '0' : '') + n}

for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  text = elements[i].textContent || elements[i].innerText;
  b = text.split(':');
  total += b[0]*60 + +b[1];
}
totalTime = (total/60 | 0) + ':' + z(total%60); // 27:24
```

Comment: I had not thought about padding a single digit! I will implement that into my code.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it a bit different:

```
var total_seconds = 0;
        // for each class of title do this
        $('.title').each(function() {
            // find class t-duration, get text and split it at the ":"
            var duration = $(this).find('.t-duration').text().split(':'),
                //parse the numbers as minutes and seconds
                minutes = parseInt(duration[0], 10) * 60,
                seconds = parseInt(duration[1], 10),
                // add them together
                total_in_seconds = minutes + seconds;
            //keep a running total
            total_seconds += total_in_seconds;
        });
        // get total minutes by dividing total_seconds by 60
        total_mins = parseInt(total_seconds / 60);
        // get remaining seconds by modulus 60 of total seconds
        total_secs = parseInt(total_seconds % 60);
        total = total_mins + ":" + total_secs;
        $('#total-time').text(total);
    });
```